# Using a VPN to do transcription work

Tags: vpn

I want to continue my transcription job in Mexico.  If I use a VPN will I be able to prevent them from discovering that I am  without being found outside the Country?

Comment: You are essentially asking us for help in bypassing a specific policy (must be in the country) for your own gain. Such questions are off-topic. In general VPN can help in hiding your original location by providing you with a public IP address from a different location. But there are several other things which can be done to detect your location where a VPN does not help. Since it is unknown what measures are in place to find out your location it cannot be said the a VPN will prevent "them" from discovering the location.